# v8 extracting a global object from nodejs in C++

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, v8

I have compiled nodejs using the "--shared" configure option. In my C++ code I have started a script in node (in its own thread) :

```
node::Start(argc, argv);
```

I have executed the following javascript to put an object into the global space :

```
global.someObject = new SomeObject;
```

I am now in C++ (on another thread) and I want to access the global "someObject". I have been thinking of using code along these lines, however the isolate vairable is NULL :

```
     v8::Isolate*  isolate = v8::Isolate::GetCurrent();
     v8::HandleScope scope(isolate);
     auto context = isolate->GetCurrentContext(); // no longer crashes
     auto global_obj = context->Global();
     v8::Local<v8::Value> objinfo = global_obj->GetHiddenValue(v8::String::NewFromUtf8(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), "someObject"));
```

Any pointers or ideas ?
How do you get a valid isolate variable from node in C++ ?

Comment: "on another thread" - that is not going to work, you can to access them from javascript event loop thread when control flow passes through your code. If you are looking for a way to provide some async behavior then you need to integrate into libuv event loop.

Comment: Happy to do that by creating a C++ function ... but is there a simple example out there on how to do it ? i.e. register a C++ callback function to pull the global out of the nodejs system. Get nodejs to execute that function. I guess it would be just as good for nodejs to pass the object to the c++ function as a variable !

Comment: For example [https://nodeaddons.com/c-processing-from-node-js-part-4-asynchronous-addons/](https://nodeaddons.com/c-processing-from-node-js-part-4-asynchronous-addons/).

Comment: I've been using SWIG to generate the addons - however it is hard to work out what is going on in the SWIG wrapper, perhaps I should create a custom C++ addon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run `isolate->Exit()` from the main thread and call `isolate->Enter()` from the other thread. You should also use v8::Locker and v8::Unlocker APIs. There are some examples [here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/refs/heads/lkgr/test/cctest/test-lockers.cc).